# Creating PDF push buttons with PDFBox 2.0.5 that shows/hides another button on the page. Only the last set created works properly

Tags: java, pdfbox

The goal of this code is to have a thumbnail image on the page, and when hovered over by the mouse it shows the image in full size. The code here works with the major caveat that only the final thumbnail-full image combo created will work unless in Adobe Acrobat Pro, I go to Tools > Interactive Objects > Add Button. then all of the buttons visible on the screen will work. If I pass the mouse over any thumbnail, then the large button associated with it is removed from the opened document. I have tried setNeedAppearances(true) and the actions will work for all combos, but the widget formatting is removed. Attached below is my test code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);

        float[] location = new float[]{100 , 600 , 60 , 80};
        TestButton.makeButton(document , page , location , "1.jpg");

        float[] location2 = new float[]{100 , 400 , 60 , 80};
        TestButton.makeButton(document , page , location2 , "2.jpg");

        document.save("mytest.pdf");
        document.close();

    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSString;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionHide;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDAnnotationAdditionalActions;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDPushButton;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestButton {

    public static void makeButton(PDDocument document , PDPage page , float[] thumbLocation, String imageName) throws IOException {
        PDImageXObject image = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("src//main/resources/" + imageName, document);
        // thumbLocation array
        float thumbX = thumbLocation[0];
        float thumbY = thumbLocation[1];
        float thumbWidth = thumbLocation[2];
        float thumbHeight = thumbLocation[3];

        float lowX = page.getMediaBox().getLowerLeftX();
        float lowY = page.getMediaBox().getLowerLeftY();
        float highY = page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY();

        float fullX = thumbX - image.getWidth() - 10;
        if (fullX < lowX + 10){
            fullX = thumbX + thumbWidth + 10;
        }
        float fullY = (thumbY + thumbHeight / 2) - (image.getHeight() / 2);
        if (fullY < lowY + 10){
            fullY = thumbY + thumbHeight + 10;
        }
        if (fullY + image.getHeight() > highY - 10){
            fullY = thumbY - image.getHeight() - 10;
        }
        float fullWidth = image.getWidth();
        float fullHeight = image.getHeight();

        String thumbImage = imageName + "_Thumb";
        String fullImage = imageName + "_Full";
        PDColor colourBlack = new PDColor(new float[] { 0, 0, 0 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);

        // Set up thumbnail
        COSDictionary thumbDict = new COSDictionary();
        PDAcroForm thumbAcro = new PDAcroForm(document , thumbDict);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(thumbAcro);
        thumbAcro.setFields(new ArrayList<>());

        PDPushButton thumbButton = new PDPushButton(thumbAcro);
        thumbButton.setPartialName(thumbImage);
        // Thumbnail actions
        thumbDict.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString(fullImage));

        PDActionHide actionHide = new PDActionHide();
        actionHide.setT(thumbDict);

        PDActionHide actionShow = new PDActionHide();
        actionShow.setT(thumbDict);
        actionShow.setH(false);

        PDAnnotationAdditionalActions additionalActions = new PDAnnotationAdditionalActions();
        additionalActions.setE(actionShow);
        additionalActions.setX(actionHide);
        // Thumbnail widget
        PDAnnotationWidget thumbWidget = thumbButton.getWidgets().get(0);
        thumbWidget.setActions(additionalActions);
        thumbWidget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(thumbX, thumbY, thumbWidth, thumbHeight));
        // Thumbnail appearance
        PDAppearanceDictionary thumbAppearanceDict = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
        PDAppearanceStream thumbAppearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
        thumbAppearanceStream.setResources(new PDResources());
        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary thumbFieldAppearance
                = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
        thumbFieldAppearance.setBorderColour(colourBlack);
        thumbWidget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(thumbFieldAppearance);
        try (PDPageContentStream thumbContent = new PDPageContentStream(document, thumbAppearanceStream))
        {
            PDRectangle thumbBox = new PDRectangle(
                    thumbWidget.getRectangle().getWidth(), thumbWidget.getRectangle().getHeight());
            thumbAppearanceStream.setBBox(thumbBox);
            thumbContent.setNonStrokingColor(0, 0, 0);
            thumbContent.setLineWidth(0.5f);
            thumbContent.addRect(thumbBox.getLowerLeftX() + 0.5f, thumbBox.getLowerLeftY() + 0.5f,
                    thumbBox.getWidth() - 1, thumbBox.getHeight() - 1);
            thumbContent.stroke();
            thumbContent.drawImage(image , thumbBox.getLowerLeftX() + 0.5f, thumbBox.getLowerLeftY() + 0.5f,
                    thumbBox.getWidth() - 1, thumbBox.getHeight() - 1);
        }
        thumbAppearanceDict.setNormalAppearance(thumbAppearanceStream);
        thumbWidget.setAppearance(thumbAppearanceDict);
        thumbWidget.setHidden(false);
        thumbWidget.setPrinted(true);

        page.getAnnotations().add(thumbWidget);
        thumbAcro.getFields().add(thumbButton);

        // Set up full
        COSDictionary fullDict = new COSDictionary();
        PDAcroForm fullAcro = new PDAcroForm(document , fullDict);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(fullAcro);
        fullAcro.setFields(new ArrayList<>());

        PDPushButton fullButton = new PDPushButton(fullAcro);
        fullButton.setPartialName(fullImage);
        // Full widget
        PDAnnotationWidget fullWidget = fullButton.getWidgets().get(0);
        fullWidget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(fullX - 1 , fullY - 1, fullWidth + 2 , fullHeight + 2));
        // Full appearance
        PDAppearanceDictionary fullAppearanceDict = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
        PDAppearanceStream fullAppearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
        fullAppearanceStream.setResources(new PDResources());
        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fullFieldAppearance
                = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
        fullFieldAppearance.setBorderColour(colourBlack);
        fullWidget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(fullFieldAppearance);
        try (PDPageContentStream fullContent = new PDPageContentStream(document, fullAppearanceStream))
        {
            PDRectangle fullBox = new PDRectangle(
                    fullWidget.getRectangle().getWidth(), fullWidget.getRectangle().getHeight());
            fullAppearanceStream.setBBox(fullBox);
            fullContent.setNonStrokingColor(0, 0, 0);
            fullContent.setLineWidth(1);
            fullContent.addRect(fullBox.getLowerLeftX() + 1, fullBox.getLowerLeftY() + 1,
                    fullBox.getWidth() - 2, fullBox.getHeight() - 2);
            fullContent.stroke();
            fullContent.drawImage(image, fullBox.getLowerLeftX() + 1, fullBox.getLowerLeftY() + 1,
                    fullBox.getWidth() - 2, fullBox.getHeight() - 2);
        }
        fullAppearanceDict.setNormalAppearance(fullAppearanceStream);
        fullWidget.setAppearance(fullAppearanceDict);
        fullWidget.setHidden(true);
        fullWidget.setPrinted(false);

        page.getAnnotations().add(fullWidget);
        fullAcro.getFields().add(fullButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: In each `makeButton` call you reset the **AcroForm** definition (actually even twice!) doing `document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm` with a newly generated `PDFAcroForm` instance, so in each call your document loses all previously existing form elements from the form definition (they remain as widget annotations but they are lost from the form).

Comment: Current version is 2.0.20.

Comment: So solving this problem by resetting the AcroForm definition multiple times is a no go? Would I be on the right path by formatting through the COSDictionary, specifically ``` thumbDict.setItem(COSName.MK);``` and somehow changing the TP and I keys under that subtype? I hope that makes sense, sorry I only started programing 2 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mkl, you sent me in the right Direction. I ended up making the TestButton class non-static and moved the Acroform definition to the main class. I am making the AcroForm without the Dictionary as that is set in the TestButton class.  Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);

        PDAcroForm buttonAcro = new PDAcroForm(document);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(buttonAcro);
        buttonAcro.setFields(new ArrayList<>());

        TestButton button = new TestButton();

        float[] location = new float[]{100 , 600 , 60 , 80};
        button.makeButton(document , page , location , "1.jpg" , buttonAcro);

        float[] location2 = new float[]{100 , 400 , 60 , 80};
        button.makeButton(document , page , location2 , "2.jpg", buttonAcro);

        document.save("mytest.pdf");
        document.close();

    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSString;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionHide;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDAnnotationAdditionalActions;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDPushButton;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestButton {

    public void makeButton(PDDocument document, PDPage page, float[] thumbLocation, String imageName,
                           PDAcroForm buttonAcro) throws IOException {
        PDImageXObject image = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("src//main/resources/" + imageName, document);
        float thumbX = thumbLocation[0];
        float thumbY = thumbLocation[1];
        float thumbWidth = thumbLocation[2];
        float thumbHeight = thumbLocation[3];

        float lowX = page.getMediaBox().getLowerLeftX();
        float lowY = page.getMediaBox().getLowerLeftY();
        float highY = page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY();

        float fullX = thumbX - image.getWidth() - 10;
        if (fullX < lowX + 10){
            fullX = thumbX + thumbWidth + 10;
        }
        float fullY = (thumbY + thumbHeight / 2) - (image.getHeight() / 2);
        if (fullY < lowY + 10){
            fullY = thumbY + thumbHeight + 10;
        }
        if (fullY + image.getHeight() > highY - 10){
            fullY = thumbY - image.getHeight() - 10;
        }
        float fullWidth = image.getWidth();
        float fullHeight = image.getHeight();

        String thumbImage = imageName + "_Thumb";
        String fullImage = imageName + "_Full";
        PDColor colourBlack = new PDColor(new float[] { 0, 0, 0 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);

        // Set up thumbnail
        COSDictionary thumbDict = new COSDictionary();

        PDPushButton thumbButton = new PDPushButton(buttonAcro);
        thumbButton.setPartialName(thumbImage);
        // Thumbnail actions
        thumbDict.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString(fullImage));

        PDActionHide actionHide = new PDActionHide();
        actionHide.setT(thumbDict);

        PDActionHide actionShow = new PDActionHide();
        actionShow.setT(thumbDict);
        actionShow.setH(false);

        PDAnnotationAdditionalActions additionalActions = new PDAnnotationAdditionalActions();
        additionalActions.setE(actionShow);
        additionalActions.setX(actionHide);
        // Thumbnail widget
        PDAnnotationWidget thumbWidget = thumbButton.getWidgets().get(0);
        thumbWidget.setActions(additionalActions);
        thumbWidget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(thumbX, thumbY, thumbWidth, thumbHeight));
        // Thumbnail appearance
        PDAppearanceDictionary thumbAppearanceDict = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
        PDAppearanceStream thumbAppearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
        thumbAppearanceStream.setResources(new PDResources());
        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary thumbFieldAppearance
                = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
        thumbFieldAppearance.setBorderColour(colourBlack);
        thumbWidget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(thumbFieldAppearance);
        try (PDPageContentStream thumbContent = new PDPageContentStream(document, thumbAppearanceStream))
        {
            PDRectangle thumbBox = new PDRectangle(
                    thumbWidget.getRectangle().getWidth(), thumbWidget.getRectangle().getHeight());
            thumbAppearanceStream.setBBox(thumbBox);
            thumbContent.setNonStrokingColor(0, 0, 0);
            thumbContent.setLineWidth(0.5f);
            thumbContent.addRect(thumbBox.getLowerLeftX() + 0.5f, thumbBox.getLowerLeftY() + 0.5f,
                    thumbBox.getWidth() - 1, thumbBox.getHeight() - 1);
            thumbContent.stroke();
            thumbContent.drawImage(image , thumbBox.getLowerLeftX() + 0.5f, thumbBox.getLowerLeftY() + 0.5f,
                    thumbBox.getWidth() - 1, thumbBox.getHeight() - 1);
        }
        thumbAppearanceDict.setNormalAppearance(thumbAppearanceStream);
        thumbWidget.setAppearance(thumbAppearanceDict);
        thumbWidget.setHidden(false);
        thumbWidget.setPrinted(true);


        page.getAnnotations().add(thumbWidget);
        buttonAcro.getFields().add(thumbButton);


        // Set up full
        PDPushButton fullButton = new PDPushButton(buttonAcro);
        fullButton.setPartialName(fullImage);
        // Full widget
        PDAnnotationWidget fullWidget = fullButton.getWidgets().get(0);
        fullWidget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(fullX - 1 , fullY - 1, fullWidth + 2 , fullHeight + 2));
        // Full appearance
        PDAppearanceDictionary fullAppearanceDict = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
        PDAppearanceStream fullAppearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
        fullAppearanceStream.setResources(new PDResources());
        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fullFieldAppearance
                = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
        fullFieldAppearance.setBorderColour(colourBlack);
        fullWidget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(fullFieldAppearance);
        try (PDPageContentStream fullContent = new PDPageContentStream(document, fullAppearanceStream))
        {
            PDRectangle fullBox = new PDRectangle(
                    fullWidget.getRectangle().getWidth(), fullWidget.getRectangle().getHeight());
            fullAppearanceStream.setBBox(fullBox);
            fullContent.setNonStrokingColor(0, 0, 0);
            fullContent.setLineWidth(1);
            fullContent.addRect(fullBox.getLowerLeftX() + 1, fullBox.getLowerLeftY() + 1,
                    fullBox.getWidth() - 2, fullBox.getHeight() - 2);
            fullContent.stroke();
            fullContent.drawImage(image, fullBox.getLowerLeftX() + 1, fullBox.getLowerLeftY() + 1,
                    fullBox.getWidth() - 2, fullBox.getHeight() - 2);
        }
        fullAppearanceDict.setNormalAppearance(fullAppearanceStream);
        fullWidget.setAppearance(fullAppearanceDict);
        fullWidget.setHidden(true);
        fullWidget.setPrinted(false);

        page.getAnnotations().add(fullWidget);
        buttonAcro.getFields().add(fullButton);
    }
}
```